# How do I search for data by first two and last two characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex, where-clause

I am working with a large database with over 1,000 products. Each product has an SKU code. I have am developing a script where certain products are removed depending on the first two and last two characters. I was wondering if there was a quick way to do delete these using MySQL only.

Is there a way I can use the WHERE statement to search for values that start with "XX" and end with "XX"?

If not then I don't mind doing it the good old PHP way, I just think a MySQL way would be more effiencient.

Many Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple delete statement

```
delete from products
where sku_code like 'XX%XX'
```

if you want products, which either start with XX or end with XX use an or condition

```
delete from products
where sku_code like 'XX%'
      or sku_code like '%XX'
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f9f/1/0) for testing.

Comment: would where sku_code like 'XX%XX' be the same as where sku_code like 'XX%' AND sku_code like '%XX'?

Comment: @PeterStuart Yes this is equivalent. See the SQL Fiddle, you can comment either delete and will get the same result.

Comment: I will give it a go right now.  I should start reading my SQL books lol!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `LIKE` clause in the where statement, i.e.

```
....
WHERE sku LIKE 'xx%' OR 
      sku LIKE '%xx'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE operator to look for a specific pattern and use % for wildcards.

In your case you can use the following:

```
DELETE FROM Products
WHERE SKUCode LIKE 'XX%' OR SKUCode LIKE '%XX';
```

You can read up more on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).